# Is Git commit and Git Push Branch Specific

Tags: git, github, branch

I'm currently working on a git branch, so I cloned it and started to modify stuff as usual, however if I commit the usual way (git add . -> git commit -m "" -> git push) would it push to the correct branch? or is there a specific command I need to do, I am working on code in production, so I don't accidentally push to the wrong branch

Comment: A most reliable method is not to omit parameters. It encounters fewer errors to use `git push origin HEAD:master` than `git push`, by explicitly specifying the remote like `origin`, the source revision like `HEAD` before the colon, and the target ref like `master` after the colon. With parameters being omitted, the command could fail due to improper configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `git branch -vv` will show you to which branch `git push` will push by default. For example, in a local repository on my system, running `git branch -vv` shows:

```
$ git branch -vv
* devel              c557af4 [origin/devel: ahead 14, behind 26] Add tests for create_sprint_board
  devel.stgit        f51dcdd goto
  master             4239189 [upstream/master: behind 6] disable create-sprint-boards pending #10
  save/before-squash d5b7980 add tests for create_sprint_board
  work               8bf0290 log warning if --copy-cards and no previous board
```

Here we see that running `git push` on the the `devel` branch will push to the `devel` branch of the remote named `origin`, and running `git push` on the `master` branch will push to the `master` branch of the remote named `upstream`.

Other branches -- like `work` -- don't have a "tracking branch" associated with them yet. On those branches, running `git push` will result in:

```
fatal: The current branch work has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin work
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that you have Git 2.0 or later and/or have `push.default` configured to `simple`. Pre-2.0, the default is `matching` for push.

Comment: A valid point, although Git 2.0 was released in 2014 so I think it's probably a safe assumption these days.

Comment: Well, except for all these questions that keep popping up, even as late as last month, that are from people using ancient RedHat or CentOS systems, running Git 1.7.9 or 1.8.3.  (Why, I'm not sure, but it still seems amazingly popular...)